# How to delete particular record in the wrapper class records in repeat function without selection option in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

How to delete particular record in the wrapper class records in repeat function without selection option in visualforce page?i am returning different object values in wrapper class. i need to delete particular record in repeat function. can any body give me an example.

Comment: Can you add some more details about you problem like snap of code.

Comment: you can post your code here

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your controller as a parameter to your wrapper, so you can call a reset function after deleting the base record. Something like this:

```
public class YourWrapper{

    public SObject obj { get; set; }
    public Boolean selected {get;set;}

    private YourPageController controller;

    public YourWrapper(YourPageController controller, SObject obj){
        this.controller = controller;
        this.obj = obj;
        this.selected = false;
    }

    public void del(){
        delete this.obj;
        controller.resetContainers();
    }
}
```

You call the reset to force the list of wrapper to refresh, and then it is removed from the page.

p.s.: if you do take this approach, make sure to use transient keywords on the controller, or your viewstate can explode.